# TikZ with "remember picture" compiled with pdflatex yields different results compared to dvips -> ps2pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, ps2pdf, dvips, rendering

The following document

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node [draw] (a) {%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      line 1 \\
      line 2
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \coordinate (line2);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \\
      line 3 \\
      line 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
  };

  \node [draw, right=5cm of line2] (a) {a};

  \draw (line2) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields a different result when I compile it to PDF using `pdflatex` compared to using `dvips` and then `ps2pdf`.

For instance, here is the (expected) figure produced by `pdflatex`:
[image]

And here is the (incorrect) figure produced by `dvips` and `ps2pdf`:
[image]

Why is this, and how do I fix it so that the result is always like the one produced by `pdflatex`?

Comment: Imho it is a bug in tikz. The dvips-route has problems when the paper size is not a4. See also this discussion (in german) http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=73803.

Comment: But I'm using A4 format, and there is no difference if I pick some other format.

Comment: No you are not. The default paper format of the article class is letter. It could be that your pdf has another format as you are not using one of the packages which will ensure that the pdf paper size and the latex paper size are the same (article is too old and doesn't do it). Add e.g. `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}`, or load the graphicx package.

Comment: I've changed the document class to be the same as in mine original document. Still the same results, and I've tried loading the `geometry` package as well with `a4paper` as option. But is there anything I can do to make this work with dvips-ps2pdf?

Comment: @gablin Why do you want to go the detour over dvi and postscript?

Comment: @mrf: Actually, I usually use `pdflatex`, but in this document the original author used `dvips-ps2pdf` so I continued with that, seeing no reason to change it. However, my concern is that if I submit a paper with TikZ figures to a conference, and they happen to use the `dvips-ps2pdf` approach, I want to make sure that the end result at their end looks exactly like I see on my machine. So I want to find out what's the problem here. =)

Comment: Well, there's always the option to compile TikZ into external files and use `\includegraphics`...

Comment: @user946850: Not sure that works when the conference requires that the paper consists of a single TeX document.

Comment: The conference doesn't want figures in their papers? Pardon me?

Comment: @user946850: No, you misunderstood. Conferences do indeed want figures, but sometimes they require that the entire paper consists of a single TeX document. This means the figures must be part of the TeX document and cannot thus be generated as separate files and then included. And if they happen to use the `dvips-ps2pdf` approach and I use the `pdflatex` approach when generating my paper, I want there to be no discrepancies between the produced PDFs.

Comment: No plots? No raster images?

Comment: @user946850: Now _that_ I haven't figured out yet how they would solve it. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a TikZ/pgf bug with `remember picture` via `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`...

In this particular case, the `matrix` library offers an elegant workaround (working via `pdflatex` and via `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \matrix [draw,matrix of nodes] (m){
    line 1 \\ % node m-1-1
    line 2 \\ % node m-2-1
    line 3 \\
    line 4 \\
  };
  \node [draw, right=5cm of m-2-1] (a) {a};
  \draw (m-2-1) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Funnily, this is _exactly_ how I solved it! ^^